# MySQL/MariaDB: Scaling 10 millions database in cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, clustering

This is for SaaS app (currently in MySQL-InnoDB). Each app contains about 150 tables. The database size is not big, but the number is high.

For each database, InnoDB create directory in `/var/lib/mysql`. Because too many database, I choose to have individual database per app to prevent file system bottleneck (Performance degrading badly if too many files/directories exist under a directory).

I will upgrade once it reach 5000 databases.

I need to know if MariaDB cluster or MySQL cluster able to deal with 10 millions database or more, or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 million databases is too many to have in one cluster and will likely hit a bunch of internal limits and be unable to balance workloads. You should look into containerizing the databases so you have one small DB associated with each client.

Answer (score 0):

150*5000 is a lot of tables.

`table_open_cache` may be too low.  And there may be other issues.  If you would like further analysis, follow the instructions [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis).

10M databases is implemented as 10M subdirectories in a single parent directory.  The OS, not MySQL, will probably croak.